# How to style and position Material UI Link component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to style and change position of a Link component, I'm trying to have the Link (Forget Password?) at the right end, but now it's centered as shown in the image below

[image]

Also I want to change the color of it, I tried `color="black"`  but didn't work

I'm using grids trying to have the texts apart from each other.

**The Code**

```
{/* Password */}
          <Grid container mt={4}>

            <Grid item xs={6} justify={"flex-start"}>
            <Typography 
            variant="h9" 
            gutterBottom 
            component="div"
            style={{ fontWeight: "bold", textAlign: "left"}} 
            >
            Password
            </Typography>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={6} justify={"flex-end"}>
          <Typography
          variant="body2"
          gutterBottom
          component={Link}
          // align="right"
          to="/register"
          >
            {/* <Link to="/register">Forget Password?</Link> */}
            Forget Password?
          </Typography>
          
          </Grid>
          

          </Grid>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `component` prop? Also, you know 'h9' is not a valid variant, right? It would help if you could provide a code sample reproducing this, it's difficult to debug css issues since it's impossible to tell if the issue is in the provided snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to right-align your password link:

```
<Grid item xs={6}>
  <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end">
    <Typography
      variant="body2"
      gutterBottom
      component={Link}
      // align="right"
      to="/register"
    >
      {/* <Link to="/register">Forget Password?</Link> */}
        Forget Password?
    </Typography>
  </Box>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

If "black" isn't defined in your theme, that won't work. `color="primary"` should work, but if you can also define black as a color in your theme.

Alternatively, if you want only this link to be black, you can add the attribute `sx={{ color: 'black' }}` to `<Link>` and that should work.

If it's not necessary to do so, I wouldn't wrap the link in a typography; just apply all the styles directly to link, as link already uses a typography element under the hood.